# How to get the data from one gridview to another gridview in windows form application?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using two grid view in the same form, I want to pass the selected entire row to another grid view, I have tried so far but not getting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
       private void dataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int selectedIndex=dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index;
            CopyColumns();          
            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; i++)
                dataGridView2.Rows[0].Cells[i].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[selectedIndex].Cells[i].Value;
        }

        void CopyColumns()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; i++)
                dataGridView2.Columns.Add(i.ToString(),dataGridView1.Columns[i].HeaderText);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    internal static class DataGridViewExtensions
    {
        public static void CloneRowWithValues(this DataGridViewRow SingleRow, DataGridView Target)
        {
            DataGridViewRow Results = (DataGridViewRow)SingleRow.Clone();
            for (Int32 Row = 0; Row < SingleRow.Cells.Count; Row++)
            {
                Results.Cells[Row].Value = SingleRow.Cells[Row].Value;
            }
            Target.Rows.Add(Results);
        }
    }
```

Source :http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3969bcad-f131-4843-89e2-57a91705fe4e/form1-gridview-selected-rows-data-sendtransfer-on-form2-gridview-rows-by-button-click

Answer (score 0):

Here solution for ur problem:

```
DataGridView1.Rows.Add(DataGridView2.Rows[0].Clone());
```

instate of `0` u can use selected index which u want to move from DGV2 to DGV1.

Answer (score 0):

For The Selected Row from **Gridview_1** Use This Code & Event (Say an **RowHeaderMouseClick**  Event)

```
private void dataGridView1_RowHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
            DataRow r=dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
            Pass_To_Grid2(r);  // Send to Other Grid View..
}

private void Pass_To_Grid2(DataRow r)
{
     dataGridView2.Rows.Add(r); /// Must have Same Fields
}
```

Please use some Advanced Features like `Drag & Drop`. This gives ow-some added  feature (user friendly application.)